# Name collision when defining a macro using pgfkeys

Tags: macros, pgfkeys

(Please suggest a better title!)

The following LaTeX document defines a macro called
`/PrintStuff`. This macro uses `pgfkeys` to define one optional
argument, `rowidstring`. The macro `\rowidstring@tables` is used to
store the value assigned to that argument.

If I pass the macro `\rowidstring` as the value to the `rowidstring`
argument, I get the following error.

```
! Use of \rowidstring doesn't match its definition.
\pgfkeys@code ... ->\edef \rowidstring @tables{#1}
```

This problem disappears if I use `\foobar`, for example.

Clearly TeX is unhappy that I'm using the same string `\rowidstring`
as part of the name of two different macros, but beyond that I'm not
clear what the problem is.

And technically aren't `\rowidstring@tables` and `\rowidstring` two
different macro names?

Running a trace on the document produces huge quantities of output,
but nothing I can understand.

Also, it's convenient to use the same string in both places as I am doing here. So is there a workaround that will let me do this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pgf}

\pgfkeys
{
  /printstuff/.is family, /printstuff,
  default/.style =
  {
    rowidstring,
  },
  rowidstring/.estore in = \rowidstring@tables,
  rowidstring/.default = {},
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\PrintStuff}{O{}}
{
  \pgfkeys{/printstuff, default, #1}%
  \typeout{ROWIDSTRING is \rowidstring@tables}
}

\newcommand{\rowidstring}{id1,id2}
%\newcommand{\foobar}{id1,id2}

\begin{document}

\PrintStuff[rowidstring=\rowidstring]
%\PrintStuff[rowidstring=\foobar]

\end{document}
```

Comment: you are missing \makeatletter

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Oh, I see. Yes, that fixes this example. Thank you. Does that mean there is nothing wrong with this usage, then? Though now I'm wondering why it doesn't give an error when I use `\foobar`.

Comment: I didn't look, I only saw the space before the @ `\edef \rowidstring @tables{#1}` and guessed ...

Comment: Though my actual code has the definition of the macro in a .sty file, so that should be OK, shouldn't it? I'll go back and check.

Comment: Your usage is fine as long as you don't miss the `\makeatletter`. It works if you don't pass in `\rowidstring` as part of the value because the only usage after your key assignment has the correct parameter pattern (literal `@tables` immediately following). In your `.estore in` it is tried to fully expand `\rowidstring` without `@tables` following (and each time you use `\PrintStuff` your `default` resets the faulty definition).

Comment: Hi @Skillmon,

Thank you for your explanation. However, I don't understand it yet. If you or anyone else are curious about my context, I had the code above in a sty file, which should have worked. Unfortunately, I also had an unnecessary `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` pair in that sty file. Which would have worked fine, except I had added some code after the `\makeatother` command, which presumably broke things. To put it another way, the `\makeatother` command was in the middle of the file rather than at the end.

Comment: Clearly it's better not to use `\makeatletter` at all in style files, because this sort of thing can happen.

So, what to do with this question? 1) Delete 2) Close 3) You or someone else answers it. If you do answer it, please expand a bit on why it works if one does not pass in `\rowidstring`, because a little more detail might help me understand it. So which of these is the best option? Please advise.

Comment: I'll answer it if you long for an explanation, but don't have the time right now, so please be a bit more patient, maybe in a couple of hours :P Or egreg comes and steals the show :)

Comment: @Skillmon An answer would be appreciated, though I don't know if "long" is quite the right word. No rush. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Lets first reduce what `.estore in` does. Your key is in principle identical to

```
\edef<macro>{<value>}
```

But `pgfkeys` doesn't check whether `<macro>` really is a single token. In your case `@` is of category 12, and hence your `rowidstring` is identical to

```
\edef\rowidstring @tables{<value>}
```

If you use this you define a macro `\rowidstring` that has the argument pattern `@tables` (so expects that literal input directly following it).

Each time you call `default` you do `\edef\rowidstring @tables{}` so you define the macro to expect the input `@tables` and expand to nothing. When you use that in your code everything's fine, because your usage of `\rowidstring` is normally followed by `@tables` in `\PrintStuff` (because you originally wanted to use the control word `\rowidstring@tables`).

Now in your breaking usage of `\PrintStuff[rowidstring=\rowidstring]` what you implicitly do is

```
\edef\rowidstring @tables{} % the effect of `default`
\edef\rowidstring @tables{\rowidstring}
```

The first overwrites your `\newcommand{\rowidstring}{id1,id2}` by the macro expecting to be followed by `@tables`. The second then uses this macro, but it is followed by `}` and not by `@tables`. TeX tries to expand that in `\edef`, but it can't and throws the error

```
! Use of \rowidstring doesn't match its definition.
```